# How to make the following SQL code faster

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write an Oracle SQL Developer code, which will summarize selected clinical events of each patient, which occurred at the day of admission, by the date of their admission (beg_effective_dt_tm) for certain services and nursing units. It requires many, many hours to run...

Wanted to reach out if anyone has any ideas, on how to speed-up the code. Thank you in advance

```
SELECT ENCNTR_ID, ROUND(BEG_EFFECTIVE_DT_TM,'DDD'), max(ventilator), max(O2FLOW), max(FIO2), min(PAO2), min(SPO2) FROM (
SELECT UNIQUE
EN.ENCNTR_ID,
ELH.BEG_EFFECTIVE_DT_TM,
max (CASE WHEN ce.event_cd = '43504571' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) OVER (PARTITION BY elh.encntr_id, round(performed_dt_tm,'DDD')) AS ventilator,
max (case when ce.event_cd = '111123182' then ce.result_val else '' end) over (partition by elh.encntr_id, round(performed_dt_tm,'DDD'))  as O2FLOW,
max (case when ce.event_cd = '14611845' then ce.result_val else '' end) over (partition by elh.encntr_id, round(performed_dt_tm,'DDD'))  as FIO2,
min (case when ce.event_cd = '6758629' then ce.result_val else '' end) over (partition by elh.encntr_id, round(performed_dt_tm,'DDD'))  as PAO2,
MIN (Case When Ce.Event_cd = '51517102' Then Ce.Result_val Else '' End) OVER (PARTITION BY elh.ENCNTR_ID, ROUND(PERFORMED_DT_TM,'DDD'))  As SPO2

FROM
ENCOUNTER EN
join CLINICAL_EVENT CE on EN.ENCNTR_ID = CE.ENCNTR_ID
right JOIN ENCNTR_LOC_HIST ELH ON EN.ENCNTR_ID = EN.ENCNTR_ID

WHERE 
CE.EVENT_CD IN ()


AND elh.MED_SERVICE_CD IN (29279,29280, 32177, 32182, 29243, 32187, 32201, 32202, 10795466, 32209) 
AND elh.LOC_NURSE_UNIT_CD IN (95785229, 95785312, 95785470, 95785577, 95780475, 95780595, 95781786 ,95782289, 95784755, 95784860, 95785057, 95785139,95785789, 95785888, 95786353, 95786453)
AND CE.PERFORMED_DT_TM >= '01-JAN-2011' 
AND CE.PERFORMED_DT_TM < '01-JAN-2012' 
AND ROUND(CE.PERFORMED_DT_TM, 'DDD') = ROUND(ELH.BEG_EFFECTIVE_DT_TM, 'DDD') 

)
GROUP BY ENCNTR_ID, ROUND(BEG_EFFECTIVE_DT_TM,'DDD')
ORDER BY ENCNTR_ID, ROUND(BEG_EFFECTIVE_DT_TM,'DDD')
```

Comment: This is better suited to the Code Review Stack Exchange site.

Comment: First, this looks wrong: `ON EN.ENCNTR_ID = EN.ENCNTR_ID`. Did you mean `ON EN.ENCNTR_ID = ELH.ENCNTR_ID`. You copied and pasted and did not retype, right?

Comment: Second, where you say `CE.EVENT_CD IN ()` do you mean `CE.EVENT_CD IN ( '43504571', '111123182','14611845', '6758629', '51517102' )`

Comment: Good catches @BobKaufman ! Also after the corrections mentioned run a execution plan of your sql and post it here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about optimizing working code (SQL) and not a programming problem. It is possibly more suitable for [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: @KenWhite this code demonstrably does not work (see Bob Kaufmans' comments) and is accordingly off-topic for codereview. Additionally optimizing working code **is** in fact a quite specific programming problem. Style-recommendations and general reviews are not. While CodeReview also does performance-reviews, questions asking only for performance are not that well recieved there, since they do not allow critique on every aspect of the code (which includes styling, best-practices and so on)

Comment: `WHEN CE.EVENT_CD IN ()`?

Comment: +1 on Bob Kaufman's answer.  If that is the code, then that mistake turns an "equijoin" into a cross join.  I've seen that kind of mistake before and it can make a seemingly innocent query take hours (and be very, very wrong).

Comment: @Vogel612: Thanks for your input, but you're incorrect. According to the **poster**, it works and simply needs to be made **faster**. In fact, it's stated **twice** (once in the title, and once with *it requires many, many hours to run*, which **explicitly** states that it works as written. If you'd prefer, you can vote to close it as off-topic because the poster either failed to state the real question or failed to provide the actual code in question. [codereview.se] was specifically created for peer review of code in order to make it better or more performant.

Comment: @KenWhite The definition of 'working' is different between CodeReview and Stackoverflow. Simply running without erroring is not enough to be deemed 'working as intended'. Just because it runs it doesn't mean it does what I want. I can assure you that the question is currently not aceptable for CodeReview. If you wish to discuss this matter further feel free to drop me a notice in chat or ask on meta

Comment: @Vogel612: Apparently we agree to disagree. I'm familiar with both this site and CR. I really don't see any need to discuss it any further; IMO, the question should be on CR, and you don't think so. Fortunately (or unfortunately, depending on your point of view) it's my vote to cast as I see fit. :-) If others don't agree with my view, the vote will expire.

Comment: @KenWhite "I'm familiar with both this site and CR." With neither questions nor answers on the latter? I find that hard to believe. Compare that to Vogel, who has almost 10k rep on the site.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: Thanks for your input, and for taking the time to look at my profile. You failed to look at mine on this site, which is considerably higher than Vogel's. (If Vogel's *almost 10K* there are relevant, so is my respective rep here, which you seem to not consider.) Apparently we're both familiar with our respective favorite sites. Vogel can feel free to vote to close questions on CR that he/she deems off-topic there as well.

Comment: Just to clarify, my comments here are not intended to address the close-votes concerning stackoverflow (This question is IMO grey area) but the mentioning / recommendation of CodeReview as an alternative for this specific question, which isn't a good recommendation to make

Comment: @Vogel612: And just to clarify, my original comment said the question was *possibly more suitable* for CR. *Mentioning* another site is totally appropriate, but as with any other [se] site the individual should check the site's guidelines before posting there.

Answer (score 3):

Using `distinct` with `group by` is always suspicious.  As is doing analytic functions and then aggregating.  I think you intend something like this:

```
SELECT EN.ENCNTR_ID, ROUND(ELH.BEG_EFFECTIVE_DT_TM, 'DDD') as BEG_EFFECTIVE_DT_TM,
       max(CASE WHEN ce.event_cd = '43504571' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ventilator,
       max(case when ce.event_cd = '111123182' then ce.result_val end) as O2FLOW,
       max(case when ce.event_cd = '14611845' then ce.result_val end) as FIO2,
       min(case when ce.event_cd = '6758629' then ce.result_val end)  as PAO2,
       MIN(Case When Ce.Event_cd = '51517102' Then Ce.Result_val As SPO2
FROM ENCOUNTER EN join
     CLINICAL_EVENT CE
     on EN.ENCNTR_ID = CE.ENCNTR_ID JOIN
     ENCNTR_LOC_HIST ELH
     ON EN.ENCNTR_ID = EN.ENCNTR_ID
WHERE CE.EVENT_CD IN () AND
      elh.MED_SERVICE_CD IN (29279,29280, 32177, 32182, 29243, 32187, 32201, 32202, 10795466, 32209) AND
      elh.LOC_NURSE_UNIT_CD IN (95785229, 95785312, 95785470, 95785577, 95780475, 95780595, 95781786 ,95782289, 95784755, 95784860, 95785057, 95785139,95785789, 95785888, 95786353, 95786453) AND
      CE.PERFORMED_DT_TM >= '01-JAN-2011' AND
      CE.PERFORMED_DT_TM < '01-JAN-2012' AND
      ROUND(CE.PERFORMED_DT_TM, 'DDD') = ROUND(ELH.BEG_EFFECTIVE_DT_TM, 'DDD') 
GROUP BY ENCNTR_ID, BEG_EFFECTIVE_DT_TM
ORDER BY ENCNTR_ID, BEG_EFFECTIVE_DT_TM;
```

Some notes:

- The `RIGHT JOIN` is unnecessary because the `WHERE` clause turns it into an inner join.
- The analytic functions are all turned into simple aggregation.
- The last condition in the `WHERE` clause should go in an `ON` clause.
- The `ELSE` for the `CASE` statement is unnecessary, because aggregation functions automatically ignore `NULL` values.

Comment: Thank you all, very much for your responses.  Yes, the code works, but takes many hours to run!  Incidentally, we discovered some errors, which are appreciated. I was seeking help revising the code, or writing a different code, in order to make it run faster (similar to profiling in R).  Many thanks!  - Markos

Comment: @MarkosKashiouris . . . This version of the query can probably then be improved using appropriate indexes.

Comment: Thank you, I thought of this but my current database access rights do not allow me to make new indexes. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @MarkosKashiouris  . . . Then you need to talk to your DBA about optimizations for the specific query.